# Django - passing get_slug method in JSON

Tags: django, json

I have a model with contains a `get_slug` definition:

```
def Specimen(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_slug(self):
        return '%s/%s-%d' % (slugify(self.longname),self.collection.collection_code, self.accessionnumber)
```

In my view I want to do this:

```
 def show_detail(request):
    specimens = Specimen.objects.filter(...)
    specimen_data = []
    for s in specimens:
        specimen_tuple = (str(s.get_slug), format(s.latdecimal), format(s.longdecimal))
        specimen_data.append(related_tuple) 

    context['specimen_data'] = simplejson.dumps(specimen_data)
```

But when I try to do something with the slug in js (though I have the same result in the shell) I find something like `<bound method Specimen.get_slug of <Specimen: Specimen object>>` instead of my slug.

How can I force the method to be evaluated prior to passing to JSON?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `s.get_slug` with `s.get_slug()` so that you actually call your method.